# "Missing { inserted" after adding tilde

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to add a tilde over some letters of an equation. Yet, the program tells me that

```
Missing { inserted. 
<to be read again> 
    \gdef l.253 ...B =\widetilde{b}+ \widetilde{A} x_\bar{b}
                                                             \\
```

This the disfonctionning part of my program:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  x_B =\widetilde{b}+ \widetilde{A} x_\bar{b}\\
  z =\underbrace{\alpha}_{scalaire}+\tilde{C}^T x_\bar{B}\\
  x_B,x_\bar{b}\ge 0\\
\end{cases}
x_B=
\end{equation*}
```

It seems either to be a fool mistake which I can't find or to be an error above in the document, isnt't it?
Can you give me some help?

Comment: You should write `x_{\bar b}`.

Comment: Yes, It worked! But why? I thought it was unecessary for single elements, and `x_\bar b` is a single element isn't it?

Comment: No, the single is `\bar`.

Comment: unrelated but `_{scalaire}` should be `_{\mathit{scalaire}}` the default math font is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but as a product of variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use braces for the subscript: `x_{\bar b}`.

Also, you can use `\\[1ex]` for example to increase a little the vertical space between lines in `cases`.

I'd use `\text{}` from `amsmath` package to write text in math mode.

Finally, notice that you should use `&` to insert conditional cases.

I think that what you want is almost this:

```
\begin{equation*}
x_B = \begin{cases}
       x_B =\widetilde{b}+ \widetilde{A} x_{\bar b} \\[1ex]
         z =\underbrace{\alpha}_{\text{scalaire}}+\tilde{C}^T x_{\bar B} \\[1ex]
      x_B, & x_{\bar b}\ge 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd write `{}+\tilde{C}^T` in the second line; otherwise the `C` is too close to the `+`. Given the length of the word "scalaire" a `\mathclap` from `mathtools` may be nice too.

Comment: @campa, yes, there are many improvements to be done in the code.